# Preciso gerar um pdf com uma imagem por página

Tags: javascript

```
createpdf(){

   var date = new Date()

   var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'),
   margin = 0.5, // inches on a 8.5 x 11 inch sheet.
   verticalOffset = margin

   var logoImage = '/images/logo/logo1.jpg'
   *convertImgToBase64(logoImage, function(base64Img){
       pdf.addImage(base64Img, 'PNG', 10, 10, '', '', '', 'FAST')
   })
   pdf.setLineWidth(0.1)
   pdf.setFontSize(20)
   pdf.text(50, 15, 'Orçamento: '+this.orcamento.id+' - Data: '+('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +  date.getFullYear())
   pdf.line(48, 18, 200, 18)
   pdf.setFontSize(12)
   pdf.text(50, 23, 'Oficina: '+this.orcamento.oficinas[0].nome)
   pdf.line(48, 25, 200, 25)
   pdf.text(50, 30, 'Endereço: '+this.orcamento.oficinas[0].endereco+', '+this.orcamento.oficinas[0].numero)
   pdf.line(48, 32, 200, 32)
   pdf.text(50, 37, 'CNPJ: '+this.orcamento.oficinas[0].cpf)
   pdf.line(48, 39, 200, 39)
   pdf.text(50, 43, 'E-mail: '+this.orcamento.oficinas[0].email)
   pdf.line(48, 45, 200, 45)
   pdf.line(48, 18, 48, 45)
   pdf.line(200, 18, 200, 45)

   for (let i = 0; i < this.orcamento.itens.length; i++) {
      let descricao = $('#desc'+i)[0]
      let line = 50
      var itemImage = '/storage/orcamentos/'+this.orcamento.itens[i].imagem
      convertImgToBase64(itemImage, function(base64Img){
         pdf.addImage(base64Img, 'PNG', 10, 180, '', '', 'a'+i, 'FAST')
      })
      pdf.fromHTML(
         descricao
         , 87 // x coord - left
         , 50 // y coord - top
         , {'width': 113}
      )
      //line += 130
      pdf.addPage()
   }

   let arquivo = 'Orçamento-'+this.orcamento.id+'.pdf'

   function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
         let img = new Image()
         img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
         img.onload = function(){
            let canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS')
            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            canvas.height = this.height
            canvas.width = this.width

            ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,canvas.height,canvas.width)
            let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png')
            callback(dataURL)
            canvas = null
         };
         img.src = url
         resolve()
      })

   }
   setTimeout(function() {
      pdf.save(arquivo);
   }, 3000);
   //pdf.save(arquivo)
},
```

O problema é que as imagens estão sendo colocadas ao final e sobrepostas. Deveria ficar uma imagem com o texto ao lado em cada página! Por exemplo a primeira imagem que deveria aparecer na primeira página, aparece na última! Eu precisar tipo "esperar" carregar e converter as imagens antes de gravar!

Comment: No git "MrRio" penso ter a resposta ao problema https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/101

Comment: Não é o caso de pageSplit, o problema é que as imagens não estão sendo carregadas. Agora se eu coloco um alert e espero para dar ok, funciona!